# Check all individual digits are even in a range

Tags: python, python-3.x

The problem statement:
Find all such numbers between m and n (both included) such that each digit of the number is an even number.The first line contains value m and n separated by a comma.The numbers obtained should be printed in a comma-separated sequence on a single line.
Constraints:
1000<=m<=9000 and
1000<=n<=9000

My solution:

```
inp=input()
arr=inp.split(',')
m=int(arr[0])
n=int(arr[1])
num=[]
for i in range(m,n+1):
  t=i
  while t>0:
    j=t%10
    if j%2==0:
      t/=10
    else:
      break
  if t==0:
    num.append(i)
for i in range(len(num)):
  if i!=len(num)-1:
    print(num[i],end=',')
  else:
    print(num[i],end='')
```

For example, if m=2000, and n=2010, then the output should be 2000,2002,2004,2006,2008

But I do not get any output. What is the fault in my program?

Comment: If each digit of the number is an even number, why should 2010 be in the output?

Comment: I don't understand why you have two iterators over your range (a while and for). One of those is enough for what you want. Using both just makes everything convoluted. All you have to do is iterate through your range and test whether your current index is divisible by two with no remainder (making it even). You can also drop your last five lines for a simple join() statement, which will convert a list into a string with a given delimiter.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.

Comment: First of all, make it easy for us to help you.  Using meaningless variable names harms the readability of your program.  Also, you've made no attempt to trace the data and control flow.  See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in python 3 `/` performs floating point division, not floor division. Change `t /= 10` to `t //= 10`.

In Python2, `3 / 4` => `0`. In Python 3, `3 / 4` => `0.75` and `3 // 4` => `0`. And your algorithm relies on floor division (or integer division), to eliminate digits.

Answer (score 2):

```
def all_even(number):
    num_str = str(number)
    digit_bool = []
    for digit in num_str:
        if int(digit) % 2 == 0:
            digit_bool.append(True)
        else:
            digit_bool.append(False)
    return digit_bool

mylist = [i for i in range(2000, 2011) if all(all_even(i))]
```

Returns

```
[2000, 2002, 2004, 2006, 2008]
```

If you want to print it:

```
print(','.join([str(i) for i in mylist]))
```

Comment: There are contraints as well

Answer (score 0):

Both your initial number and the end number have a number of digits. Valid digits are 0, 2, 4, 6, 8. Now, the first thing you need to do is to find the first number which is greater than or equal than the smallest number and all its digits are pair. If the initial number has an unpair digit, then it needs to be increased to the next pair number. If the digit is not the last, then all other digits behind it will become 0 values. Once you have the first valid number, you can repeat printing the current valid number and increasing the last digit by two, until you either reach the end number or 0 as the last digit. If you reached the last number, your routine is finished. If you did not reach the last number, then your last digit is 0, the penultimate is increased by two. You handle the penultimate digit as you handled the last digit.

Answer (score 0):

You can condense this quiet a bit. First take your input, then use *list comprehension*  with split to convert the two numbers to `ints`. From here w can use *list comprehension* to build a list within the range of the two numbers only taking `not i % 2` which would be our even numbers. Finally we can unpack and print that list, using a separator. In addition we can add a while loop and innate our m, n to 0, to comply with our contraints.

```
m, n = 0, 0
z = range(1000, 9001)
while m  not in z or n not in z:
    x = input()
    m, n = [int(i) for i in x.split(',')]
lst = [i for i in range(m, n + 1) if not i % 2]
print(*lst, sep=', ')
# 2000, 2002, 2004, 2006, 2008, 2010
```

Answer (score 0):

Using List Comprehensions python3.4 
*e.g. to find numbers between 1000 and 9001 which has each of its digit as even*

***1. Check if the number itself if even***
***2. If Yes, then iterate over each digit of that number to check if its even***
***3. The length of it, should be equal to the length of the number***

```
 [i for i in range(1000,9001) if i%2==0 and len([int(j) for j in list(str(i)) if int(j)%2==0])==len(str(i))]
```

> Output :
>   [2000, 2002, 2004, 2006, 2008, 2020, 2022, .......   8880, 8882, 8884, 8886,8888]

Answer (score 0):

I found a quite easier way! 
solved it by understanding its math relation rather than writing a complex program!

```
even_digits= []
for x in range(1000,9000):
        if int(x) % 2 == 0  and int(x) % 20 < 10 and int (x) % 200 < 100 and int (x) % 2000 < 1000:
            even_digits.append(str(x))
print (','.join(even_digits))
```

This is the result:

```
2000,2002,2004,2006,2008,2020,2022,2024,2026,2028,2040,2042,2044,2046,2048,2060,2062,2064,2066,2068,2080,2082,2084,2086,2088,2200,2202,2204,2206,2208,2220,2222,2224,2226,2228,2240,2242,2244,2246,2248,2260,2262,2264,2266,2268,2280,2282,2284,2286,2288,2400,2402,2404,2406,2408,2420,2422,2424,2426,2428,2440,2442,2444,2446,2448,2460,2462,2464,2466,2468,2480,2482,2484,2486,2488,2600,2602,2604,2606,2608,2620,2622,2624,2626,2628,2640,2642,2644,2646,2648,2660,2662,2664,2666,2668,2680,2682,2684,2686,2688,2800,2802,2804,2806,2808,2820,2822,2824,2826,2828,2840,2842,2844,2846,2848,2860,2862,2864,2866,2868,2880,2882,2884,2886,2888,4000,4002,4004,4006,4008,4020,4022,4024,4026,4028,4040,4042,4044,4046,4048,4060,4062,4064,4066,4068,4080,4082,4084,4086,4088,4200,4202,4204,4206,4208,4220,4222,4224,4226,4228,4240,4242,4244,4246,4248,4260,4262,4264,4266,4268,4280,4282,4284,4286,4288,4400,4402,4404,4406,4408,4420,4422,4424,4426,4428,4440,4442,4444,4446,4448,4460,4462,4464,4466,4468,4480,4482,4484,4486,4488,4600,4602,4604,4606,4608,4620,4622,4624,4626,4628,4640,4642,4644,4646,4648,4660,4662,4664,4666,4668,4680,4682,4684,4686,4688,4800,4802,4804,4806,4808,4820,4822,4824,4826,4828,4840,4842,4844,4846,4848,4860,4862,4864,4866,4868,4880,4882,4884,4886,4888,6000,6002,6004,6006,6008,6020,6022,6024,6026,6028,6040,6042,6044,6046,6048,6060,6062,6064,6066,6068,6080,6082,6084,6086,6088,6200,6202,6204,6206,6208,6220,6222,6224,6226,6228,6240,6242,6244,6246,6248,6260,6262,6264,6266,6268,6280,6282,6284,6286,6288,6400,6402,6404,6406,6408,6420,6422,6424,6426,6428,6440,6442,6444,6446,6448,6460,6462,6464,6466,6468,6480,6482,6484,6486,6488,6600,6602,6604,6606,6608,6620,6622,6624,6626,6628,6640,6642,6644,6646,6648,6660,6662,6664,6666,6668,6680,6682,6684,6686,6688,6800,6802,6804,6806,6808,6820,6822,6824,6826,6828,6840,6842,6844,6846,6848,6860,6862,6864,6866,6868,6880,6882,6884,6886,6888,8000,8002,8004,8006,8008,8020,8022,8024,8026,8028,8040,8042,8044,8046,8048,8060,8062,8064,8066,8068,8080,8082,8084,8086,8088,8200,8202,8204,8206,8208,8220,8222,8224,8226,8228,8240,8242,8244,8246,8248,8260,8262,8264,8266,8268,8280,8282,8284,8286,8288,8400,8402,8404,8406,8408,8420,8422,8424,8426,8428,8440,8442,8444,8446,8448,8460,8462,8464,8466,8468,8480,8482,8484,8486,8488,8600,8602,8604,8606,8608,8620,8622,8624,8626,8628,8640,8642,8644,8646,8648,8660,8662,8664,8666,8668,8680,8682,8684,8686,8688,8800,8802,8804,8806,8808,8820,8822,8824,8826,8828,8840,8842,8844,8846,8848,8860,8862,8864,8866,8868,8880,8882,8884,8886,8888
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def oddnumbers (num1, num2):
  newline = 0
  for i in range(num1 + 1, num2):    # loop to go thru numbers 
    if i %2 == 0:                    # if remainder of number / 2 is 0 it is even
        print(i, end=" ")            # print i in a single line 
        newline +=1                # counter to see how many times i has iterated
        if newline == 20:          # maximum number before a new line is started
          print()                   
          newline = 0                # reset new line counter
                                

num1 = 1000
num2 = 3000

oddnumbers(num1, num2)
```